# Tauri app not connecting to localhost after building

Tags: macos, tauri

My tauri Macbook App is designed to connect to a local server that runs on the Macbook, even while the app is in production.

While working on the app, the app connects but after building into DMG, the app can no longer connect to the local server (e.g. http://localhost:3456)

What can I do?